# PHP Converting Custom Array to Specific Object Structure

Tags: php, json

I have an array of data that needs to be converted into a specific structure so that it will be loaded properly by a 3rd party plugin.

The current closest array I was able to achieve is this below, From here I am stuck.

php array

```
 [
        [
            ["item1"],
            ["itemname"],
            ["item desc"],
            ["05\/14\/2014"]
        ],
        [
            ["item12"],
            ["itemname2"],
            ["item desc2"],
            ["05\/14\/2014"]
        ]
    ]
```

json_encoded

```
[ 
 0 => [0 => "Value1", 1 => "Value2", 2 => "Value3" ], 
 1 => [0 => "Test", 1 => "Test2", 2 => "Test3" ], 
 2 => [0 => "Random1", 1 => "Random2", 2 => "Random3" ]
]
```

How do I convert it to have a structure like this,

```
[
  {"0":"Value1","1":"Value2", "2":"Value3"},
  {"0":"Test", "1":"Test2","2":"Test3"},
  {"0":"Random1","1":"Random2","2":"Random3"},
]
```

Any Idea will be appreciated, Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Is that supposed to be a JSON string?

Comment: yes nick it is json string

Comment: It's invalid as the keys of the object must be enclosed in quotes...

Comment: i'll update the json string

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are no attempts provided in your question

Comment: I've only put the last output I was able to achieve, because other procedures I did seems to be irrelevant to the question I have since I am stuck in a particular output. 

I'm getting value from the database in json_encode and serialize data and uses eloquent to to retrieve data from variable and loop into json_encoded unserialize data, the data by default is an associative array, that I converted to just one dimentional array so that it will be easier to construct into the format I need to achieve. So I am stuck in that final array and needs some suggestion where to start from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a JSON string representing an array of objects by casting all your array elements to objects before `json_encode`. However this will give string keys, not numeric keys (which are not valid JSON):

```
$array = [ 
 0 => [0 => "Value1", 1 => "Value2", 2 => "Value3" ], 
 1 => [0 => "Test", 1 => "Test2", 2 => "Test3" ], 
 2 => [0 => "Random1", 1 => "Random2", 2 => "Random3" ]
];

foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    $arr = (object)$arr;
}
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "0": "Value1",
        "1": "Value2",
        "2": "Value3"
    },
    {
        "0": "Test",
        "1": "Test2",
        "2": "Test3"
    },
    {
        "0": "Random1",
        "1": "Random2",
        "2": "Random3"
    }
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NsbTb)

**Update**

Based on the edits to the question, it looks like you're looking for this:

```
$array = [
        [
            ["item1"],
            ["itemname"],
            ["item desc"],
            ["05/14/2014"]
        ],
        [
            ["item12"],
            ["itemname2"],
            ["item desc2"],
            ["05/14/2014"]
        ]
    ];

foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    $arr = (object)array_map(function ($a) { return $a[0]; }, $arr);
}
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "0": "item1",
        "1": "itemname",
        "2": "item desc",
        "3": "05\/14\/2014"
    },
    {
        "0": "item12",
        "1": "itemname2",
        "2": "item desc2",
        "3": "05\/14\/2014"
    }
]
```

Demo on 3v4l.org

Comment: Hi I like your answer, but I have some problem, the array i provided is json_encoded already, I cannot foreach in the json_encode array, I have edited my question and added the actual array without encoding, thank you very much

Comment: @apelidoko the original array PHP array is quite different. What output do you expect from that?

Comment: I'm expecting the same output you were able to achieve, I'm actually using Ajax datatable, the problem is it only accepts the data in that format

Comment: @apelidoko is this perhaps what you're looking for: https://3v4l.org/8WsGv?

Comment: Thank You Very Much Nick, you've been so helpful,

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
json_encode($your_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
```